# Use CDN files with HTML5 app cache

Tags: html

Chrome basically can't retrieve any CDN files (jQuery, AngularJS) I have specified in my index.html since I cannot have them under CACHE: directive (they are not in my domain).

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v1.0.7

CACHE:
/partials/account_items.html
```

How can I make my web app work using app cache but also CDN files?

Answer (score 4):

I use // instead of / for CDN contents that should be part of the application cache. For example, my current project uses fontawesome.io and jquery:

```
CACHE:
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: if I look int he chrome network tab, it still shows jquery as getting a 304 from google. So I am not sure this is working.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you need a NETWORK section and add the domains where the jquery/angularJS is stored.

For example - both angularJS and JQuery are hosted on ajax.googleapis.com.  Assuming that's the CDN you are using, simply add that host to the NETWORK section of your cache manifest:

```
NETWORK:
http://ajax.googleapis.com
```

I blogged about this and other aspects of app cache at http://gregsramblings.com/2012/05/28/html5-application-cache-how-to/

Greg

Comment: By the way- you can specify a wildcard in this section too.

Comment: I thought the `NETWORK:` section was for items that specifically required an internet connection to be accessed(?). If I understood wingy's original question correctly, they were asking how could they instruct the browser to cache the CDN asset to make it available offline? I personally found this question because my browsers were all refusing to cache CDN assets when https:// was specified in the manifest. MattH's answer of just specifying double-slash (//) worked for me.